# Dotnet core 6 starter app with angular and identity shows certificate error when deployed to Azure App Service

Tags: .net-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice, angular13, duende-identity-server

I used the starter application in visual studio for dotnet core 6 and angular with identity and https.

I am working on a mac and I had to set up a certificate for localhost.  My app works fine locally.  However, after deploying it to Azure App Service I get this error:

`InvalidOperationException: No signing credential is configured by the 'IdentityServer:Key' configuration section.`

Do I need to create and upload a certificate to my Azure App Service?  And also make code changes to use my created certificate both locally and on the deployed app?